# How can I create area under in line in Dygraph

Tags: dygraphs

I have seen the "Stacked" charts in Dygraph gallery, and I would like to create something similar but WITHOUT the stacking. i.e. just fill the are below the line to the y-axis zero line with a chosen colour.

Is this possible?

What options would I need to provide?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, in your options array, you can set it to fillGraph as below

```
{
    legend: 'always',   
    title: 'Graph Name',   
    ylabel: 'Incoming MBps',   
    xlabel: 'Date Time',   
    fillGraph: true,   
    stackedGraph: false
}
```

Here is the rest of the reference:

http://dygraphs.com/options.html#fillGraph

Comment: How can I set the fillGraph color? Is a gradient fill here possible?

Answer (score 0):

register to the   underlayCallback callback give you access to the canvas
and then use canvas operation to draw what you need

```
underlayCallback: function(context, area, dygraph) {

canvas = context;
dygr = dygraph              
// use this value to get the with and height

canvasWidth =  context.canvas.width
canvasHeight = context.canvas.height

canvas .beginPath();
canvas .fillStyle= `rgba(255,0,0,0.2)`;
for (let i=0 ; i< data.length ; ++i){
    let p = data[i];
    p = [dygraph.toDomXCoord(p[0]), dygraph.toDomYCoord(p[1])];
    if(i === 0){
        canvas.moveTo(p[0],p[1]);
        continue;
    }
    canvas .lineTo(p[0],p[1]);
}
canvas.fill();
}
```